# manipulate div contents for jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

Hello I have a div having a partial view inside

```
<div id="popup" style="display:none">@Html.Partial("_checkAddParticipant")</div>
```

What I would like to do is add some string at the beginning of contents of div and show as a jquery dialog as follows:

```
 function OpenConfirmationDialog(message)
{  
    $('#popup').dialog();
};
```

I would like to add message string at the beginning of content comes from partial view. The message is generated at runtime just before calling function so I do not have a chance to add message string in partial view.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just set the message before you open the dialog? Like changing a static element with jQuery, it doesn't matter if it's a dialog or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var actual_html = $( "#popup" ).html();
$('#popup').html("String to add" + actual_html);
$('#popup').dialog();
```